# RAM compatibility between different different generations and recommendations

Tags: memory, motherboard

My PC has the following:

- Asus Sabertooth X79 Motherboard
- QuadCore Intel Core i7-4820K, 3633 MHz
- [4x4GB Kingston KHX1866C9D3/4GX](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820104296) DDR3 1866, CL9, 1.65V, Quad Channel

I'd wanna throw another 16GB and go for DDR4.

My questions would be:

- Are there any incompatibilities between using a DDR3 gen vs DDR4? 1866MHz vs 2400/2800/3000? CL9 vs CL14/15/16? Voltage? Anything else?
- Would a HyperX Savage/Fury/Predator w/ Black be a good candidate?
- Other manufacturers maybe? ($300 tops)

Comment: Shopping recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: Your motherboard doesn’t support DDR4.  You cannot put DDR4 on a DDR3 motherboard.